# Microsoft windows presentation foundation error

Tags: c#, wpf, window

When deploying my wpf application when i open the window that i am using window presentation foundation controls in it it crash after usercontrol loaded event and this is the error from log viewer

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
User:          N/A
Computer:      HQMSSCUS0001K.dma.gov.local
Description:
Application: Siren.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Surface.PerformanceCounters.get_IsEnabled()
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Logger.PreNotifyInput(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.NotifyInputEventArgs)

Comment: the above is the stack trace part of it

Comment: maybe you use Surface SDK, but I don't know deeply about that. The stacktrace shows that your input items (whatever) are not a type of what Logger acceptable. try to turn off Surface logger or match your item to Logger acceptable type.

Comment: Anyway the reason is Surface Performance logger, so run surface example which does not use or display such a performance counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i am not installing **surface toolkit runtime** on the client machine